# How can I list the files in a directory on ftp server?

Tags: c#, ftp

The problem is the following:

I found a solution which can list the files and directories in the root of ftp server. But I need the content of the directories also. How need I modify  this method?

```
internal void ListFilesOnServer()
        {
            try
            {
                FtpWebRequest ftpwrq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(server);
                ftpwrq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user,passw);
                ftpwrq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                ftpwrq.KeepAlive = false;
                FtpWebResponse fresponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpwrq.GetResponse();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fresponse.GetResponseStream());
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Create));
                sw.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
                sw.Close();
                fresponse.Close();
                sr.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Gotcha");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Haven't tried it, but is System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails not what you need? Just got it from intellisense, and it seems like what you are looking for.

Comment: that's just give more details about the listed files and dirs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the following code:

```
            reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(sUri));
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(sFtpUserID, sFtpPassword);
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            reqFTP.Proxy = null;
            reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
            reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
            response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
            reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                result.Append(line);
                result.Append("\n");
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
```